# Correct formula for summation in R, calculating polymorphism information content (PIC)

Tags: r

(Genomics data jargon warning!) I am calculating the polymorphism information content (PIC) in R from a dataset of thousands of single nucleotide polymorphisms (SNPs). The data needed to make the calculation is allele frequencies. Each observation has two (rarely three) allele types either the reference or the 1st alternative. I have a small number with a 2nd alternative allele. This is the formula I am trying to code in R: [image: PIC formula] [original publication](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1686077/?page=7)

where Pi and Pj are the frequencies of ith and jth alleles for the selected SNP marker. This is my current formulation in R

```
var_freq$PIC <- (1-(var_freq$a2^2)-(1-var_freq$a2)^2)-(2*(var_freq$a2^2)*(1-(var_freq$a2^2))))
```

Where the variable `a2` is the alternative allele frequency.

The test dataset: a1 is reference allele, a2 is the alternative (still ignoring the a3 the 2nd alternative allele)

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
testdata <- data.frame(a1=rnorm(n=10000, mean = .99, sd=0.15)) %>% 
  filter(., a1<1&a1>0) %>% 
  mutate(., a2=1-a1)
```

Is this the correct R code formulation for the PIC value, i.e. am I interpreting the formula right?

Answer (score 1):

If the question is how to calculate PIC given vector p then

**1)** from 1 subtract the sum of squares of the elements of p and also subtract twice the sum of the values in the upper triangle of the o matrix.

```
p <- c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4)  # test data

o <- outer(p^2, p^2)
PIC <- 1 - sum(p^2) - 2 * sum(o[upper.tri(o)]); PIC
## [1] 0.6454
```

**1a)** Since o is symmetric the upper and lower triangles are the same so twice the upper triangle equals the sum of all elements except the diagonal which we subtract off (i.e. add it because it is already negated) so a variation is:

```
o <- outer(p^2, p^2)
PIC <- 1 - sum(p^2) - sum(o) + sum(diag(o)); PIC
## [1] 0.6454
```

**2)** alternately use the listcompr package which facilitates code that is very close to the formula shown in the question.

```
library(listcompr)
n <- length(p)
1 - sum(p^2) - 2 * sum(gen.vector(p[i]^2 * p[j]^2, i = 1:(n-1), j = (i+1):n))
## [1] 0.6454
```

### Double check

```
# double check
1 - (.1^2+.2^2+.3^2+.4^2) - 2*(.1^2*(.2^2+.3^2+.4^2) + .2^2*(.3^2+.4^2) + .3^2*.4^2)
## [1] 0.6454
```

Comment: With my test data (updated question) with allele 2 and your code I was getting -15729.07, PIC values should be between 0 and 1. I should also be getting a PIC value per loci (i.e. per location of the two alleles, by row), not a single value per allele type (i.e. reference allele or alternative allele, by column). Pardon my matric algebra ignorance, do we need the frequency of both alleles to perform the equation.

Comment: No. The formula shown in the question has one vector as input and a scalar as output.  It does NOT have a vector as output.   What you are commenting on may be some larger problem that you haven't described.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically, this is equivalent to:

```
p <- c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4)  # test data

1 - sum((s <- p%o%p) * `diag<-`(s, 1))
[1] 0.6454
```

Comment: This is very nice but although it seems to work I don't think that R guarantees that the left hand side of the * will be evaluated before the right.  For safety it might be better to place the `s<-p%o%p` in a separate line.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck R does guarantee that. I did enclose `s` in paranthesis.

Comment: Enclosing it in parenthesis makes no difference.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck could you give me a situation/scenario whereby the right side will be evaluated before the left side?

Comment: Its not a matter of how it works now.  It clearly works as I pointed out in my comment. Its more a matter of whether its guaranteed not to change.  I have posted a message to r-devel to get feedback on the issue.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I get your point in this case, in that it works here. BUt in general, I have never seen it fail. Thats why I am curious. I have used this severally, and would appreciate to know whether it is *not guaranteed to work. An example of it failing (in any case/scenario) would be enlightening.

Comment: I should also be getting a PIC value for every row in the column. Each row = a loci, at each loci there are two allele possibilities column a1 and column a2. Previously my testdata I included only had the minor allele frequency (either a1 or a2 that was the lowest frequency). Curious why my test data didn't get used?

Comment: Review [this thread](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2021-August/081054.html) on the r-devel list.  One of the R developers thought it was not guaranteed but did not seem 100% sure.